# When reloading a UITableView section, all sections flash

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm using a `UITableViewController`, and am using:

```
[self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionNumber] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

to reload an individual section of the tableview (to animate the insertion of new cells). The issue is that all of the sections, and their cells, flash white briefly every time this call is made. This does not occur if I use

```
[self.tableview reloadData];
```

but does occur no matter which row animation I use.

I'm aware that I can use `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`, but I currently have a race condition that doesn't allow me to use that. I will, at some point, fix that, but in the meantime I would like to know why all sections cells flash while I'm reloading a single section. In addition, if I can turn off the flash and just animate the insertion / deletion of cells, that would be ideal.

Comment: Could you provide some code sample?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it flashes because when you reload a specific section, it still has to recalculate the size of all the visible sections. Hence the flash. Without using insertion/deletion (because it knows the table will only change by one), you can't get past that.

If you are just trying this in the simulator though, it is possible that the flash will either disappear or be less noticeable when loaded on an actual device.

Answer (score 0):

May be it's too late. But it could help someone.

**Obj-c:**

```
[UIView performWithoutAnimation:^{
    [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:[indexPath section]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}];
```

**Swift 5:**

```
    UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
        self.tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: indexPath.section), with: .none)
    }
```